# Why is context not passed in formview django get method? Django, python

Tags: python, django

**Error in the browser** *'NoneType' object is not callable*

```
context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs) …
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
__class__   
<class 'orders.views.OrderAddView'>
args    
()
kwargs  
{'tag': 'fast'}
request 
<WSGIRequest: GET '/orders/add/fast'>
self    
<orders.views.OrderAddView object at 0x00000000056EA430>
```

Why isn't `context` passed to `get`? if accept `context` as `self.get_context_data (** kwargs)` same error

**views.py**

```
class OrderAddView(FormView):
    template_name = 'orders/order_add.html'
    formOne = SimpleOrderAddForm()
    formTwo = FastOrderAddForm()

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.formOne.prefix = 'one_form'        
        self.formTwo.prefix = 'two_form'
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({'formOne': self.formOne, 'formTwo': self.formTwo})
        return self.render_to_response(self.template_name, {'context':context})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        formOne = SimpleOrderAddForm(self.request.POST, prefix='one_form')
        formTwo = FastOrderAddForm(self.request.POST, prefix='two_form')

        if formOne.is_valid() and formTwo.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('orders_home')
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(formOne, formTwo, **kwargs)

    def form_invalid(self, formOne, formTwo, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        formOne.prefix = 'one_form'
        formTwo.prefix = 'two_form'
        context.update({'formOne': formOne, 'formTwo': formTwo})
        return self.render_to_response(self.template_name, {'context':context})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You inherit from `FormView`. What happens in `get_context_data` for form view is that if the key `form` is not in the kwargs it calls `self.get_form()` which tries the following code:

> ```
> def get_form(self, form_class=None):
>     """Return an instance of the form to be used in this view."""
>     if form_class is None:
>         form_class = self.get_form_class()
>     return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
> ```

`self.get_form_class()` simply returns `self.form_class` which for your case is `None` so in the end you end up calling `None((**self.get_form_kwargs()))`.

Looking at your implementation you have basically overriden anything of use in `FormView` and are doing everything yourself, so you should not even inherit from it. You should use [`TemplateView` Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/base/#templateview) instead:

```
class OrderAddView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'orders/order_add.html'
    formOne = SimpleOrderAddForm()
    formTwo = FastOrderAddForm()

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.formOne.prefix = 'one_form'        
        self.formTwo.prefix = 'two_form'
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({'formOne': self.formOne, 'formTwo': self.formTwo})
        return self.render_to_response(self.template_name, {'context':context})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        formOne = SimpleOrderAddForm(self.request.POST, prefix='one_form')
        formTwo = FastOrderAddForm(self.request.POST, prefix='two_form')

        if formOne.is_valid() and formTwo.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('orders_home')
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(formOne, formTwo, **kwargs)

    def form_invalid(self, formOne, formTwo, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        formOne.prefix = 'one_form'
        formTwo.prefix = 'two_form'
        context.update({'formOne': formOne, 'formTwo': formTwo})
        return self.render_to_response(self.template_name, {'context':context})
```